# Wants to store the , separated sting in array

Tags: javascript

I want to store the comma(,) separated elements in array. Below is my code

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++ ){

    temp.push({
            title:"Compared",
            columns:[
                {title:"val", field:"setting", width:"95", sortable:true, headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"feild", field:"val", formatter:"textarea", headerFilter:"input", width:"150"},
            ],
        })
        console.log(temp[0],temp[1])
}
```

My output should look like below.

temp[0]

```
{
    temp.push({
            title:"Compared",
            columns:[
                {title:"val", field:"setting", width:"95", sortable:true, headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"feild", field:"val", formatter:"textarea", headerFilter:"input", width:"150"},
            ],
        }
```

temp[1]

```
{
    temp.push({
            title:"Compared",
            columns:[
                {title:"val", field:"setting", width:"95", sortable:true, headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"feild", field:"val", formatter:"textarea", headerFilter:"input", width:"150"},
            ],
        }
```

I'm very new to javascript seems my question may not contain the required information. 
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `console.log()` inside `for`. So it not able to print that

Try this:

```js
let temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    temp.push({
            title:"Compared",
            columns:[
                {title:"val", field:"setting", width:"95", sortable:true, headerFilter:"input"},
                {title:"feild", field:"val", formatter:"textarea", headerFilter:"input", width:"150"},
            ],
        })
}
console.log(temp[0], temp[1])
```